# Getting an access is denied error from amazon web services

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, zapier

I have a client who uses zapier to connect his account and post information.

In this case he is using a Fluid Surveys account and using zapier to post the survey results in another database.

The error in question:

Problem retrieving Dropdown.

```
internal returned (401) Unauthorized and said 
"(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user
 'user'@'ec2-54-86-9-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)")"
```

Now this may seem like an easy fix, except that user isn't associated with amazon services. His fluid surveys account IS hosted on amazon however the user that is being denied access is not located on fluid surveys (which is hosted on AWS) but rather on the database which is hosted by Canada Web Hosting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly do you see this error? Within Zapier's interface? Also, what is the Zapier action you are using?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward... ec2-54-86-9-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com is the hostname of the IP address of the server that is trying to establish a connection to the database, using invalid credentials.

Comment: agree with @Michael-sqlbot - just keep in mind that in MySQL the username/password combo can also tied to an ip address. that means user/pw@192.168.1.100 is NOT THE SAME as user/pw@10.10.10.2 even if you use the exact same credentials. sounds to me like an error in Fluid Surveys' setup at Zapier.